# ColumnSeries binding data with WPF Toolkit exception

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit

I'm using `WPF Toolkit` extension to show a Column Graph that takes the data from a `Dictionary<string,ulong>` (where the strings are the X-values and the ulong the Y ones). This is the declaration of the XAML

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart x:Name="Chart" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Title="Chart Title" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="560" Width="1000">
    <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries x:Name="myGraph" DependentValuePath="Key" IndependentValuePath="Value" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

And I have an object that construct a `Dictionary <string,ulong>`

so, I declared the global variable

```
private Dictionary<string,ulong> myDictionary;
```

to store the data from my object and bind it with the chart as follows

```
this.myDictionary = myObject.objectDictionary;
myGraph.Title = "My Title";
myGraph.ItemsSource = this.myDictionary;
```

But I get the following exception:

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

So, is there I'm doing wrong with the binding?

Regards

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to determine what object is null and thus throwing the exception? It looks like you are doing your binding in the code behind. Are you doing the binding after the Initialize() call? What is "myObject"? Is it null? Does it have an objectDictionary property? Is THAT null?

Comment: I've done all, in fact there's no object null, myObject is a class that has the Dictionary<string,ulong> objectDictionary and myGraph.ItemSource is taking well the Dictionary as you can see in this screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dhhju2e0lrpa85u/Sin%20t%C3%ADtulo.jpg?dl=0

Comment: We only see the lines specific to the binding here. Can you post the whole method containing those binding lines? Additionally, can you show us which line throws the error or does it happen after the method exits? If you can narrow down where the exception is happening, you might be able to expand it and see more information about it.

Comment: Do you have the full stack trace of the problem?  That will usually point us better as to what is causing the issue.  I suspect that it is not within your own code since there is nothing wrong with the basics we see here.  Also, can you provide a test project that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the error on my program. Instead of using `ItemsSource`, I used `myGraph.DataContext` defining the `IndependentValuePath` and `DependentValuePath` properly.

```
this.myDictionary = myObject.objectDictionary;
myGraph.DataContext = this.myDictionary;
myGraph.IndependentValuePath = "Key";
myGraph.DependentValuePath = "Value";
```